# pandas iterrows overwriting values

Tags: pandas, loops, dataframe, iteration

I tried to use iterrows as a command to deal with the frame.

```
stocks2['Startpoint']=0
for index,row in stocks2.iterrows():
    if row['VOL']>4*row['avg'] and row['RET']< -0.02 :
        row['Startpoint']=1
```

I know that the condition is met several times, but it does not seem to overwrite successfully the value in that case.

```
stocks2['Startpoint'].value_counts()
```

Out[141]:
0    1588603
Name: Startpoint, dtype: int64

Comment: because `.iterows` returns an iterator over `pd.Series` objects representing the rows of your data-frame, but mutating those `pd.Series` objects will not affect the original `pd.DataFrame`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need for loop , You can do with

```
stocks2['Startpoint']=((stocks2['VOL']>4*stocks2['ave'])&(stocks2['RET']<0.2)).astype(int)
```